# Extracting String within strings using Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

Say i have this string

"Input:Can we book an hotel in Lagos ? Parse: book VB ROOT  +-- Can MD aux  +-- we PRP nsubj  +-- hotel NN dobj  |   +-- an DT det  |   +-- in IN prep  |       +-- Lagos NNP pobj  +-- ? . punct "

and i want to get a list like this

```
['book VB ROOT', 'Can MD aux',..., '? . punct']
```

using regular expression.

I have tried doing

```
result = re.findall('\||\+-- (.*?)\+--|\| ', result, re.DOTALL)
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you really have to use regex? You can achieve what you want with a simple `split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regex by playing with  built-in functions and methods:

```
>>> filter(bool, map(str.strip, s.replace('+--', '|').split('Parse:')[1].split('|')))
['book VB ROOT', 'Can MD aux', 'we PRP nsubj', 'hotel NN dobj', 'an DT det', 'in IN prep', 'Lagos NNP pobj', '? . punct']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re.split`..

```
>>> s = 'Can we book an hotel in Lagos ? Parse: book VB ROOT  +-- Can MD aux  +-- we PRP nsubj  +-- hotel NN dobj  |   +-- an DT det  |   +-- in IN prep  |       +-- Lagos NNP pobj  +-- ? . punct'
>>> re.split(r'\s*\|?\s*\+\s*--\s*', s.split('Parse:')[1].strip())
['book VB ROOT', 'Can MD aux', 'we PRP nsubj', 'hotel NN dobj', 'an DT det', 'in IN prep', 'Lagos NNP pobj', '? . punct']
```

Comment: not working this is the output  
['Can we book an hotel in Lagos ? Parse']

note the string is 
"Input: Can we book an hotel in Lagos ? Parse: book VB ROOT  +-- Can MD aux  +-- we PRP nsubj  +-- hotel NN dobj  |   +-- an DT det  |   +-- in IN prep  |       +-- Lagos NNP pobj  +-- ? . punct"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that does use a regex, but doesn't require looping over all the parts twice:

```
def extract(line):
    _, _, parts = line.strip().partition(' Parse: ')
   return re.split('(?: \|)? \+-- ', parts)

line = "Input:Can we book an hotel in Lagos ? Parse: book VB ROOT +-- Can MD aux +-- we PRP nsubj +-- hotel NN dobj | +-- an DT det | +-- in IN prep | +-- Lagos NNP pobj +-- ? . punct "
print(extract(line))
>>> ['book VB ROOT', 'Can MD aux', 'we PRP nsubj', 'hotel NN dobj', 'an DT det', 'in IN prep', 'Lagos NNP pobj', '? . punct']
```